# C# running powershell command how to pass byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, powershell

I am trying to invoke powershell command from c# code and need to pass as parameter byte array but it converts in wrong format.
C# code:

```
var command = new Command("Set-UserPhoto");
command.Parameters.Add("Identity", login);
command.Parameters.Add("Confirm", false);
command.Parameters.Add("PictureData", pictureData); //byte array
```

Actually powershell:

```
Set-UserPhoto -Identity:'hennadiy.lebedyev@itera.no' -Confirm:$False -PictureData:'255','216','255','224',...,'0','16'
```

Needed powershell:

```
Set-UserPhoto -Identity:'hennadiy.lebedyev@itera.no' -Confirm:$False -PictureData:(255,216,255,224,...,0,16)
```

Using with function AddScript powershell cannot be run.

Comment: You wouldn't do that with an actual powershell command. You'd load a file, pipe it to the command and use the piped object as the parameter. In fact, `Set-UserPhoto` works just as well with a stream instead of a byte buffer

Comment: Perhaps orthogonal to your question but why are you using C# to call to powershell?  Can't you just directly call whatever API(s) your script is using, bypassing all the powershell restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

If your "Command" class is the equivalent of **System.Management.Automation.PSCommand**, you've done it right.

Below the code I've used to perform this operation:

```
const string connectionUri = "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/?proxymethod=rps";
const string schemaUri = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange";

const string loginPassword = "password";
SecureString secpassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in loginPassword)
{
    secpassword.AppendChar(c);
}
PSCredential exchangeCredential = new PSCredential("demo@sample.com", secpassword);

WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(connectionUri), schemaUri, exchangeCredential)
{
    MaximumConnectionRedirectionCount = 5,
    AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic
};

using (var remoteRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
{
    remoteRunspace.Open();

    using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        powershell.Runspace = remoteRunspace;

        var command = new PSCommand()
            .AddCommand("Set-UserPhoto")
            .AddParameter("Identity", "user@sample.com")
            .AddParameter("PictureData", File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Test\MyProfilePictures\pic.jpg"))
            .AddParameter("Confirm", false);
        powershell.Commands = command;
        powershell.Invoke();
    }
}
```

**?proxymethod=rps** [is important to support >10Ko files](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/cloudtrek365/2014/12/31/uploading-high-resolution-photos-using-powershell-for-office-365/)

Hope that help